# Package migration from version 8 to version 6. Downgrade from ssis 2015 to 2012

Tags: ssis

I created a new project in VS 2015, when I run it on my machine it runs successfully however once I build and deploy the solution in the server it fails with the following error message:

Package migration from version 8 to version 6 failedwith error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater  than current version number"

"Error loading value "8" from node "DTS:Property".

The Target Server Version is 2012 and I have added this to the project properties.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Package downgrade is not a valid operation for SSIS.
You can try [SSIS2014 Downgrade](https://ssis2014downgrade.codeplex.com/) application from Codeplex, however, I have not tried it.
Alternatively, you can do package modification as described in [Vanie Castro's article](https://vaniecastro.com/2015/02/26/how-to-downgrade-sql-server-integration-services-2014-packages-to-2012/). This method I used myself.

Comment: Thank you Ferdipux.